# Show join linq query in a View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with ASP.net MVC, C# I have two model classes, Artist and Album, I created a new separate class called Operations to put methods in there(I have read it`s a good practice concerning to MVC to implement methods in a separate layer and not in Controller class or Model classes). I want a method to return information of both models, I created already the database with two tables Artist and Albums joined by ArtistID. I know how the query must work, but what should return that method? Do you know which is the correct way to develop this? How the controller will call this method and create a view considering that is a mix of Artist and Albums? Should I create a ViewModel specifically for this? How I can do this?

Model Classes:

```
 public class Artist
 {
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
 }

public class Album
{
        public int AlbumID { get; set; }
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }              
}
```

Operations Class: I called the method AlbumsByArtist it won`t work returning a Abum List because it returns a join between Artist and Album, what should that return? how I can use the Controller to send the results to a View and show these results in a View?

```
public class Operations
{
        MusicStoreDbContext db = new MusicStoreDbContext();
        public List<Album> AlbumsByArtist()
        {
            var temp = (from ar in db.Artists
                        join al in db.Albums on ar.ArtistID equals al.ArtistID
                        select new { al.AlbumName, ar.Name, ar.LastName });
            return temp;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a ViewModel here. ViewModels are specific to our Views where we want to display specific data according to the need. We should create View Models always for Views instead of using database models directly in View:

```
 public class AlbumsByArtistVM
 {
       public string AlbumName {get;set;}
       public string ArtistName {get;set}
       public string ArtistLLastName {get;set;}

 }
```

and return that like:

```
public List<AlbumsByArtistVM> AlbumsByArtist()
{
    var temp = (from ar in db.Artists
                join al in db.Albums on ar.ArtistID equals al.ArtistID
                select new AlbumsByArtistVM
                { 
                   AlbumName =al.AlbumName, 
                   ArtistName =ar.Name, 
                   ArtistLLastName  =ar.LastName 
                });
    return temp;
}
```